# Обязательно ли тире

Tags: пунктуация

Здравствуйте!
Подскажите, обязательно ли здесь тире: "Рекомендуемая доза (–) 500 мг, далее (–) 250 мг.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

У Розенталя: **Тире ставится**, если оба главных члена предложения выражены количественными числительными или если один из них **выражен формой именительного падежа существительного**, а другой — **числительным** либо оборотом с числительным:  *Скорость — шестьдесят километров в час.*

Рекомендуемая доза – 500 мг, далее – 250 мг.

Примечание. **В специальной литературе** при характеристике предмета **тире** в этом случае **часто не ставится**: *Грузоподъёмность крана 2,5 тонны*, *вылет стрелы 5 метров*; *Температура плавления золота 1063 о С*.

Если у Вас предложение из специальной литературы, то тире в первом случае можно не ставить: Рекомендуемая доза 500 мг, далее – 250 мг.

Answer (score 1):

Да, тире здесь поставить нужно.

*Рекомендуемая доза – 500 мг, далее – 250 мг*.

Answer (score 0):

Первое тире факультативно, я бы сказала, излишне; второе обязательно - пропущено несколько слов.

Ср.: *Мой вес 52 кг; мой рост 162 см.* Опущено слово "составляет", как и в случае с дозой.

Comment: А Вы сравните рекомендуемую дозу с рекомендуемым весом.
Рекомендуемый вес – 52 кг. Сужу чисто интуитивно, но "Рекомедуемый вес 52 кг" звучит как незаконченная фраза.